# Add javadocs to show on a webpage

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, view, javadoc, html

Is there someway that I can show my javadocs that I have generated through eclipse to show them on a webpage in my Spring mvc project? I know I gotta do something with the controller but what?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try using JAutoDoc plugin for Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the javadocs in some folder within your application (like `/WEB-INF/docs/`) and instruct Spring to serve them as [static resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources) (which they are):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/docs/**" location="/WEB-INF/docs/" />
```

You then access them with something like `http://localhost:8080/yourAppContext/docs/index.html`.

Depending on your application URL mappings it might even be possible to generate the files in a publicly available folder (outside of `WEB-INF`) and let the server itself serve them from there without triggering the Spring dispatcher servlet.

Comment: DEBUG: [aug-20 14:46:18,111] method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /docs/index.html
DEBUG: [aug-20 14:46:18,116] method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/docs/index.html]
WARN : [aug-20 14:46:18,116] web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/pyramidstatus/docs/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'restservices'

Comment: @benskiiii: As I said in my answer, you have to [instruct Spring to treat the javadoc pages as static resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources). From the comment you posted it seems that Spring is trying to map your request to a controller and fails. Review your configuration files.